# Restoring Windows 7 without Disks - What should I Know?

Tags: windows, system-restore

My brother built a computer from the ground up last year and installed Windows 7 Ultimate 64 bit onto it. The problem is that it needs to be restored to factory settings now - reason being that my other brother wants to install a new game and cannot remember what the admin password is!

This is further exacerbated by the fact that when a disc is inserted into the computer (depending on the program to run, e.g. setup.exe) it asks for the admin password thereby negating the option of using the disks.

I have read that to do this one should press the correct keys on the keyboard before the Windows 7 image pops up. So the question really is what are the correct keys? I know they depend on the manufacturer but of what? The motherboard, CPU or even the hard drive?

And after that what screen would be presented? (A screenshot would be good to demonstrate this)

Any resources that can completely explain this would be helpful.

Thanks!

Comment: It depends on the BIOS, which depends on the motherboard type.  Once you are able to boot from DVD, by the way, you can simply reset the password rather than reinstalling Windows altogether: http://harryjohnston.wordpress.com/2010/03/09/resetting-a-password-in-windows-7-or-windows-vista/

Comment: If it is only the admin pass you don't remember I once came accross a method that will enable you to remove all passwords from all win accounts including main admin password using usb with linux installation - if I find the name of the program I'll post in answer - it works 100% since I used it to delete my admin passwords.

Answer (score 1):

If you just lost the admin password and you have no "normal" way of recovering it I'd suggest to use [Hiren's BootCD](http://www.hirensbootcd.org/resetting-windows-password/)

The website has all the tutorials needed to remove the admin pass.

1. First prepare a bootable USB.
2. Copy Hiren's files on USB.
3. Follow the steps in tutorial - it's all nice and clear.

Answer (score 0):

Turn on your PC or restart it if it's already on.

Watch for a "entering setup" message in the first few seconds after turning on your computer. This message varies greatly from computer to computer and also includes the key or keys you need to press to enter BIOS.

Here are some common ways you might see this BIOS access message:

```
Press [key] to enter setup
Setup: [key]
Enter BIOS by pressing [key]
Press [key] to enter BIOS setup
Press [key] to access BIOS
Press [key] to access system configuration
```

Quickly press the key or keys instructed by the previous message to get into BIOS.

Note: You may need to press the BIOS access key several times to enter BIOS. Don't hold the key down or press it too many times or your system may error or lock up. If that happens, just restart and try again.

When you enter BIOS you can navigate the BIOS menu using the keys of your keyboard, it will look something like this:
http://0.tqn.com/d/pcsupport/1/0/H/2/-/-/biosmainmenu.jpg

Just go to the Boot Menu and locate the option for changing the boot order. Put your DVD/Disk reader first, save and restart. It should boot from the disk and then you can just do this: 
http://harryjohnston.wordpress.com/2010/03/09/resetting-a-password-in-windows-7-or-windows-vista/

I'll just copy-paste from there to in case the link breaks down:

```
Boot to your Windows 7 or Windows Vista installation DVD, whichever matches the installed OS.  If you purchased your computer from a responsible vendor, they’ll have provided you with one, although unfortunately many vendors don’t.
Additional note 8 September 2011: In Windows 7, there is an option in the Start Menu (under Maintenance) to Create a System Repair Disc.  The CD or DVD this option creates is perfect for the job.  However, you have to be an administrator to use it, so unless you’ve done it ahead of time or can use a friend’s Windows 7 machine you’re out of luck.
Additional note 1 September 2011: If your computer is 64-bit capable (you don’t need to actually be running a 64-bit OS) then you can use the install disk for Microsoft’s free server product, Hyper-V.  You can find it here.  Note, however, that it is a fairly big download, a little more than a gigabyte.
Additional note 5 May 2011: Nommo was kind enough to point me to this post on Microsoft Answers which provides a link to downloadable repair disks for Vista and Windows 7.  I can’t from my own knowledge confirm that these disks are legitimate, and Microsoft aren’t telling, so use only at your own risk.  Indications are that they are probably OK.  (Personally, I wouldn’t use the charged-download option until I’d checked how much my OEM was going to charge to provide an installation disk.  Make sure the OEM knows you need a Windows installation disk, not a system recovery disk.)
A vendor system recovery disk might offer the same functionality, and in some cases you can order an installation DVD from your vendor (or from Microsoft?).
Select your language options on the first screen and press Next to continue.
Choose “Repair Your Computer”.
Choose “Use recovery tools…” and select your OS.  Make a note of which drive letter it is on, e.g., C: or D:.  This might not be the same drive letter you see when booted normally.
Additional note 1 September 2011: if you get an error message when you press Next, this might be because the install disk you are using is not compatible with the version of Windows you have installed.  This will happen, for example, if you are using the Hyper-V install disk.  Don’t panic.  Just press SHIFT-F10 to open a command prompt and skip ahead to step 6.
Select Command Prompt.
In the command prompt window that appears, type “regedit” and press ENTER.
Select HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE and then choose Load Hive from the File menu.
Find and open the file named SYSTEM on the drive you noted in step 4.  If Windows is in the default configuration, this will be in windows\system32\config.
Enter a key name, e.g., “xxx”.
Click the plus icon to the left of HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE to open this key.  Select the xxx key.
Select Export from the File Menu.  Change the Save as type to Registry Hive Files.  Type a name for the backup, for example, systembackup, and press Save.  (This step creates a backup of the unmodified SYSTEM registry hive as a precaution.)
Open the xxx key, and select Setup.
Double-click on SetupType in the right-hand pane.  Enter 2 and press OK.
Double-click on CmdLine.  Enter cmd.exe and press OK.
Close Registry Editor.  Type “regedit” and press ENTER to open it again.  (This step does not appear to be necessary in Windows 7, but in Windows Vista if you do not do this the next step might fail with an Access Denied error.)
Open HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, select xxx, and choose Unload Hive from the File Menu.  Push Yes.
Close the command window and the Registry Editor.  Remove the installation DVD and select Restart.
When your computer boots up, another command window should appear.
Type “net user foo bar”, replacing foo with the username of the account whose password you want to reset, and bar with the new password.  For example, you might type “net user Administrator letmein”.  Press ENTER.
If you want to use the built-in Administrator account, you will probably need to enable it: type “net user Administrator /active:yes” and press ENTER.
If you don’t know what the administrative username(s) are, type “net localgroup administrators” and press ENTER to find out.
Type “exit” and press ENTER.
When the logon screen appears, use the username and the new password to log in.
```